# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable | when I using generator in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I need to create a generator that makes "n" random numbers between a high and low number (which are inputs). I managed to do this, but I didn't understand why the error occurred.

I did it in python using the Jupyter Notebook.

```py
import random
def rand_num(low,high,n):
    for x in range(n):
        print (random.randint(low,high))
--------------------------------------------
for num in rand_num(1,10,12):
    print(num)
```

I get to did it, but appear this error:

```py
8
8
2
10
4
4
3
10
1
4
6
3

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-f54bba9a72c6> in <module>()
----> 1 for num in rand_num(1,10,12):
      2     print(num)

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

I need to help for understand this error. Why this occurred?

Comment: You're returning `None` from `rand_num`, so TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The callable `rand_num` does not explicitly return anything, which is the same as returning `None`, so you're effectively writing `for num in None` which is of course impossible. What you're looking for is

```
import random

def rand_num(low, high, n):
    for x in range(n):
        yield random.randint(low, high)

for num in rand_num(1, 10, 12):
    print(num)
```